# Test for open documents

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing a simple paint application and I have added a coordinates display in the status bar. I only want it to show when there are open documents. When I start the program, it displays the idle message `Ready`.

What function would I use to test for open documents?

Here is my `OnMouseMove()` handler:

```
void CMDIView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
  // Define a Device Context object for the view
  CClientDC aDC(this);                                                 // DC is for this view

  // Verify the left button is down and mouse messages captured
  if((nFlags & MK_LBUTTON) && (this == GetCapture()))                  
  {
    m_SecondPoint = point;                                             // Save the current cursor position
    if(m_pTempElement)
    {
      // An element was created previously
      if(ElementType::CURVE == GetDocument()->GetElementType())        // A curve?
      {  // We are drawing a curve so add a segment to the existing curve
         std::static_pointer_cast<CCurve>(m_pTempElement)->AddSegment(m_SecondPoint);
         m_pTempElement->Draw(&aDC);                                   // Now draw it
         return;                                                       // We are done
      }
      else
      {
        // If we get to here it's not a curve so
        // redraw the old element so it disappears from the view
        aDC.SetROP2(R2_NOTXORPEN);                                     // Set the drawing mode
        m_pTempElement->Draw(&aDC);                                    // Redraw the old element to erase it
      }
    }

    // Create a temporary element of the type and color that
    // is recorded in the document object, and draw it
    m_pTempElement.reset(CreateElement());                             // Create a new element
    m_pTempElement->Draw(&aDC);                                        // Draw the element
  }


  {       //Coordinates display
      CString s;
      s.Format(L"X=%d Y=%d", point.x, point.y);
      CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
      CStatusBar* pStatus = &pFrame->m_wndStatusBar;
      pStatus->SetPaneText(0, s);
  }

}
```

[image: Coordinates of Mouse]

**Fixed:**

```
CMDIDoc::~CMDIDoc()
{
    CString Idle = LPCTSTR(AFX_IDS_IDLEMESSAGE);
    //Idle = LPCTSTR(L"lawlawlwawl");
    CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    CStatusBar* pStatus = &pFrame->m_wndStatusBar;
    pStatus->SetPaneText(0, Idle );
}
```

Comment: Is this a "standard" MFC application? SDI? MDI?

Comment: This is a MFC MDI application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no open documents, then calling [`MDIGetActive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99y32tyd.aspx) should return `NULL`.

However, if that's the case then you would also have no view either and the view is - I assume - the `CMDIView` class that you showed in your question.

Perhaps one alternative is to handle the display of the status bar text from your `CMainFrame` instance rather than from the view.

So (in pseudo-code) in your `CMainFrame`,

```
if (MDIGetActive() == NULL)
    // display "Ready"
else
   // ask current view for the text
```

Another alternative might be to trap the destruction of the `CDocument` and reset your status bar text to "Ready" there. As @Edward pointed out, it would be safer - and better encapsulation - to let the main frame handle the text display and let it decide whether to set the text itself based on whether the current view exists and/or wishes to provide text.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to change the status while destroying the current CDocument.


`CMDIDoc::~CMDIDoc()
{
 CString Idle = LPCTSTR(AFX_IDS_IDLEMESSAGE);
 //Idle = LPCTSTR(L"lawlawlwawl");
 CMainFrame* pFrame = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
 CStatusBar* pStatus = &pFrame->m_wndStatusBar;
 pStatus->SetPaneText(0, Idle );
}`

Comment: Setting the Statusbar on the destruction of `CDocument` is a bit risky, you could have multiple documents open

Comment: @EdwardClements Yes I agree - probably best to have control of the status bar text in the main frame class and notify from document dtors, then let the main frame decide what to do, as in my first alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
CMDIChildWnd* pActiveChild = pFrame->MDIGetActive();
if (pActiveChild && pActiveChild->GetActiveDocument())
{    // one or more documents open
}
```